Visual Studio build error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Failed to locate any simulator runtime matching options
After MacOS update Visual Studio stopped building .NET MAUI iOS project using paired Mac computer. The following error reported:
The operation couldn’t be completed. Failed to locate any simulator runtime matching options: {
    BuildVersionString = 21E210;
    Platforms =     (
        "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator"
    );
    VersionString = "17.4";
}

How can I fix this issue?

This is also the case when developing with Uno Platform with an iOS target. Added this comment to help Uno Platform devs find this question and answers. #unoplatform

The accepted answer may download simulators for platforms you don't need like WatchOS. A more refined approach is to load XCode to the XCode menu -> Settings -> Platforms and install the missing simulator(s).

I also removed about 20GB of simulators I didn't need which was a nice bonus.

What's strange to me that is I needed to download simulator runtime when I tried to debug app on actual iPhone device connected to the Mac computer.

Yes, @Rafael, it is strange.

What's also strange is, why would it need a particular version. What is forcing it to look for one particular version? Especially if the build is supposed to be for iPhone and not iPhoneSimulator? Why wouldn't we be able to specify iOs 15.2 Simulator if we have that (or need that, specifically)? Why would this be hard-coded or concealed?

On your Mac, open terminal and run the following command:
xcodebuild -downloadAllPlatforms

Wait until the command execution completes, restart your Visual Studio on Windows computer and try to build the project again.

This caused the download of at least 6GB of data that I didn't need, and didn't work either - at least initially. It did finally work after restarting the Mac. The heavy download is a minus, so it might be better to get the platforms you need in XCode under Settings->Platforms, then restart the Mac in addition to Visual Studio on Windows.

My Mac didn't require a restart. Hm. Only difference is that I'm developing using Uno Platform, not Maui.
